# SAS Proc Report spacing= option not working

Tags: sas, report

I'm doing some examples to learn the basics of proc report. For some reason I can't get the spacing= option to work, how do I fix it and what are the most used simple options to format the appearance of columns?

p.s I'm using SAS Studio

```
proc report data = ads2;
 columns subjid b c;
 define subjid / display 'Subject ID' spacing=4;
 define b / display 'One' spacing=4;
 define c / display 'Two' spacing=4;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to set the cell width:

```
    proc report data=sashelp.class; 
       col name age sex;
       define name / style(column)=[cellwidth=2in];
    define age / style(column)=[cellwidth=5in];
    define sex / style(column)=[cellwidth=.5in];
    title "Using the CELLWIDTH= Style with PROC REPORT";
    run;
```

If you want read more from this option : https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p1sh52tpsi1nxbn1sr371jj0bngj.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1sh52tpsi1nxbn1sr371jj0bngj

Answer (score 1):

The `spacing=` option is only applicable to `ODS LISTING` destination.

From the [`DEFINE Statement`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p0wy1vqwvz43uhn1g77eb5xlvzqh.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n0juhvm525pzfun1d07sxjgandcs) documentation:

> SPACING=horizontal-positions
>   defines the number of blank characters to leave between the column being defined and the column immediately to its left. For each column, the sum of its width and the blank characters between it and the column to its left cannot exceed the line size.
>   Default:    2
>   Restriction:    This option has no effect on ODS destinations other than the LISTING destination.

Start learning more about `REPORT` styling from the documentation ["Using ODS Styles with PROC REPORT"](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=p14xegao6xt0xnn1865r422tpytw.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> Most Base SAS procedures that support ODS use one or more table templates to produce output objects. These table templates include templates for table elements: columns, headers, and footers. Each table element can specify the use of one or more style elements for various parts of the output. These style elements cannot be specified within the syntax of the procedure, but you can use customized styles for the ODS destinations that you use. For more information about customizing tables and styles, see "TEMPLATE Procedure: Creating a Style Template" in *SAS Output Delivery System: Procedures Guide*.